# Display data in Arrray Horizontally

Tags: php, arrays

I've created and array and it works just how I wanted it to. The final part I wanted to attempt is to output the data horizontally but not sure how to.

```
<?php 

    $date = "2015-11-25";
    $t = 0;


    $startdate = "2009/06/01";

    $start = strtotime($date);

    $currentdate = $start;

    $times_table = array();
            for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++){
                $times_table[$i] = array();

            }
    echo "<pre>";

           for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++){
                 for($j = 0; $j <= 2; $j++){

                   if ($j == 0){
                    $times_table[$i][$j]=  "Version 4" ;
                }
                    else if ($j == 1){
                    $cur_date = date('Y/m/d', $currentdate);

                    $currentdate = strtotime('+1 month', $currentdate);

                    $times_table[$i][$j]= $cur_date ;

                    }
                    else{
                        $times_table[$i][$j]=  "good" ;
                    }
                }

                }


    print_r($times_table);
     echo "</pre>";
        ?>
```

Comment: Can you be a little more clear with what you're asking for? Perhaps add a diagram of the output you're looking for.

Comment: Can you explain better how you need data horizontally. Do you think of visual horizontally (using html css) or you think or reordering array in some way. Please put what you get now and whay you like array to look like. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but this looks like it should be in a table. For example:

```
<?php 

    $date = "2015-11-25";
    $t = 0;


    $startdate = "2009/06/01";

    $start = strtotime($date);

    $currentdate = $start;

    $times_table = array();
            for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++){
                $times_table[$i] = array();

            }

           for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++){
                 for($j = 0; $j <= 2; $j++){

                   if ($j == 0){
                    $times_table[$i][$j]=  "Version 4" ;
                }
                    else if ($j == 1){
                    $cur_date = date('Y/m/d', $currentdate);

                    $currentdate = strtotime('+1 month', $currentdate);

                    $times_table[$i][$j]= $cur_date ;

                    }
                    else{
                        $times_table[$i][$j]=  "good" ;
                    }
                }

                }
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr><th>Version #</th><th>Date</th><th>Status</th></tr>';
    foreach($times_table as $times){
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($times as $t){
            echo '<td>',$t,'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';

?>
```

I should note that I would strongly discourage outputting raw data such as with `print_r` or `var_dump` for anything but debugging purposes that cannot find their way into the real world. It can be very bad for security.